# Django [ create userS with specific permission ]

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm developing an E-Learning Platform, however, there are a specific requirement.

First the Admin Can create 2 type of Users [ Teacher - Student ]

Admin:

Only the Admin can Create a Course and HomeWorkS for a specific Course.

Assign Teacher to a specific course and can only view it, no other Courses are accessible to him.

Assign a Student to a specific Homework and\or course.

Teacher:

The Teacher can only See the Course [ it's been assigned to ] and The homeworkS and Can Ask Student to re-Do it.

Student :

Student - Can only see the homeWorks and submit it and re-Do it if the Teacher request it.

I tried DRY principle but I couldn't solve the issue.

Any help Is really appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: What is your particular issue?

Comment: Can not Create a specific User [ Teacher - Student ]  With it's permission.

Comment: First thing is to extend the Abstract User and add two fields, `Teacher`, `Student`. Use `user = User.objects.get()` and then `if user.is_superuser = True: ...`. Unsure what seems to be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem right, a model structure like this should get you started.  I've purposefully elided the imports, etc., as they should be obvious or easily googleable.

```
class User(AbstractUser):  # This model should be set as the AUTH_USER_MODEL in the settings.
    # The views to create courses should check whether `request.user.is_teacher` is true.
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # Likewise, the views one uses to assign courses or homework to users should check
    # whether the target user's `is_student` value is true.
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Course(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='courses_as_teacher')
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='courses_as_student')
    # Add a name field, etc.


class Homework(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    assignees = models.ManyToManyField(User)  # (students)
    # Add a name field, etc.
```

You'll probably also need a `HomeworkReply` model to model a given student's "reply" to a homework assignment.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me a lot of time, as i was trying to do each one as an APP. Thank you.